# MongoDB retrieve all documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get all docs from mongoDB, my code looks like this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/catalog', function(err, db) {
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        var cursor = db.collection('products').find(function(err, cursor) {
            cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                console.log(doc);
            });     
        });
    });
});
```

I don't get anything printed out though and I can't figure out where's the problem. If I put a query string (i.e. find({"name":"Samsung note"})) it works fine and returns products.

Where's my mistake?

tnx!

update: something's wrong even when I call for a single product, cursor.count() returns nothing.

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
        db.collection('products').find({"upc": "027242799219"}, function(err, cursor) {
            var cnt = cursor.count();
            console.log(cnt);     
        });
    });
```

update(take 2): I went to the other mongoDB .find() question and copied code from the answer:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/catalog', function(err, db) {
    theDB = db;

    db.open(function(err, db) {
        if (err) return console.log('error opening db, err = ', err);
        console.log("db opened!");
        db.collection('products', function(err, collection) {
            if (err) return console.log('error opening users collection, err = ', err);
            collection.find().limit(100).toArray(function(err, results) {
                if (err) return console.log('error initiating find on users, err = ', err);
                else    
                    {
                        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                             {
                                 console.log(results[i]);
                             }
                        db.close();
                        console.log("CLOSED");
                    }                         
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Now... this prints the result, BUT if I put a breakpoint on console.log or I try to do something with results[i] (such as write it to elastic) the app is unresponsive. I can see in the task manager that it uses more and more CPU/memory without actually hitting my breakpoint.

What the what?

Comment: try `find({}, function(err, cursor))`

Comment: nope, didn't work :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js MongoDB query not returning results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696444/node-js-mongodb-query-not-returning-results)

Comment: find retrieves the cursor.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.1/lib/collection.js Line 163

Comment: If you have another question then [Ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Changing your question from what you originally asked is misleading and not really polite towards those who responded.